# ASP.NET MVC how to connect to SQL Server and create new database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986730/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day

I have problem with day 3 in first step - Step 1 – Create Database. I don't know how do this.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I added this DB, this is the tree in SQL Server Object Explorer
[image]
I have an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

in return

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        SalesERPDAL salesDal = new SalesERPDAL();
        return salesDal.Employees.ToList();
    }
```

This is my connectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb);Initial Catalog=SalesERPDB;Integrated Security=True"
            name="SalesERPDAL"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I added DB in App_Data project folder

Comment: Visual Studio has a "Server Explorer" pane which can connect to a database.  Conversely, the database itself should have some kind of tool for connecting and managing databases.  (Such as SQL Server Management Studio.)

Comment: @David I updated the question

Comment: Try to add your SQL instance name to the datasource ("LocalDb\MSSQLLocalDB")

Comment: @Reinard Works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have installed SQL Server Management Studio? an easy way to create a database is using this tool.

Just connect to the local instance and you will see a folder named DataBases, then Right-click > New Database...a window will appear to name this database as you wish